# systemctl failed to execute because it isnt a directory

Tags: systemd

I've made the switch to Linux for my storage server / plex server. I've installed the dependencies for sonarr (mono), and everything runs when I run the command to start sonarr. I'm trying to get it to start automatically, and not require me to leave a terminal window open.

Here is my Sonarr Script, according to their site, it works. https://pastebin.com/ewjd0w0G

Now, with that back story, I can explain further as to what my problem is. I'm following this [tutorial](https://github.com/Sonarr/Sonarr/wiki/Autostart-on-Linux) and when I get to the section where it says "systemctl enable sonarr.service"

I get this error;
"dreadstarx@us01-storage-01:~$ systemctl enable sonarr.service
Failed to execute operation: Not a directory

Seems as if I'm the only person having this problem because I haven't found any forums posts or questions on AskUbuntu. I've tried to chmod it to +x, and it doesn't do anything.

What the hell did I do wrong?

Comment: __FORGIVE__ for asking is that file not supposed to be in `/etc/systemd/system` rather than `/usr/lib/systemd/system/` as specified in that tutorial?

Comment: Please move it there and try to enable it again...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run this command to find the failing command

```
  strace -f systemctl enable sonarr.service
```

This will log every system call made by the operation to STDOUT.
The failing command will be one of the last ones run. From what you could be able to figure out what is being referred by the "not a directory" diagnostic message.

Answer (score 0):

Hah! I feel a little special now. I figured out why it wasn't working, well a friend pointed it out. I was missing / after service when I moved it.

Thanks for the help!